# When working with floating point numbers, is it good to normalize between 0 and 1?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

I have numbers in the range of let's say 1e10 and 1e11. Is it better to normalize those numbers to [0;1] before making any calculations and/or comparisons for the sake of accuracy? I wonder because I heard that between 0 and 1 there are as many representable numbers than from 1 to infinity. However I can't find a source for that.

Comment: Scaling: it can make sense to get the original exponents close to 0 to reduce the risk of over/underflow. Translating: it can indeed sometimes help to center things around 0 (for instance between -1 and 1), but you want to make sure not to lose more in the translation than you win afterwards. -> question is too general.

Answer (score 3):

You can't increase the precision of an existing floating point number. There is no "hidden" precision that can be recovered through normalization, on the contrary, normalization is more likely to reduce the precision of a number due to rounding error. That said, there are some mathematical operations that may produce a more precise result if the inputs are normalized in some way first, but that depends specifically on the operations you are performing.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers are stored in memory in, well, floating point, that is scientific notation. That is `1.23456789e10`, `1.23456789e-10` and `1.23456789` will all hold the same number of significant digits.

It is true that, mathematically, there are infinite numbers between 0 and 1, (that would be Aleph-1?), but that is irrelevant to the discussion, because a floating point variable can only hold so many different values. For example a 4-byte floating point variable has 32 bits, so it is impossible to make more than 2^32 different floating point values.